# CV formatting and writing software?

Tags: cv, software, formatting

Is LaTex everyone's go to for writing a professional CV? Or are there other niche tools/packages that you use to format and write it? i.e. something like a WYSIWG graphical editor with preset formatting, but specifically for CVs. Ideally, something that enforces a strong separation between content and style, so that you can easily swap out styles for the same content

Comment: You have to be a bit careful what you wish for.  The extreme of this are systems like Digital Measures, where you enter all your accomplishments into a form and a CV is generated automatically.  Unfortunately, the requirement to handle all possible types of CV entry means that it handles none of them well, and the generated CV is basically unusable.

Comment: LaTeX is flexible enough to format something pretty much however you want, so why not use it? If you learn how to create your own templates and .sty files it also becomes easy to change the style while maintaining the content.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I guess you are right, I was looking for a "free lunch". If I want a good looking CV, *and* have it be customisable and portable, then I'll have to probably bite the bullet and make it myself with Latex.